# Client Side is not Authenticating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, create-react-app, mern

This is my client/App.js file

```
import { StrictMode, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import User from "./User";
import Login from "./Login.js";
import CreatePost from "./CreatePost";
import Post from "./Post";
import axios from "axios";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Edit from "./Edit.js";
function App() {
  const [file,setFile] = useState(null);
  const [post,setPost] = useState({
    title: "",
    image: "",
    content: ""
  }
  );
  function change(event){
    const {name,value} = event.target;
    if (name==="image"){
      setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    }
    setPost((prevValue)=>{
      return name==="title"?{...prevValue,title:value}:(name==="image"?{...prevValue,image: value}:{...prevValue,content: value});
    })
  }
  const [login,setLogin] = useState(false);
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`+"/success");
      const fetchData = async function(){
        await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`+"/success",{credentials: "include"}).then((res)=>{res.json().then((data)=>{console.log(data.message);setLogin(data.message); })})}
      fetchData();
      console.log(login);
    },[]);
 
  function click(){
    console.log(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`+"/auth/google");
    window.open(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`+"/auth/google","_self");
  }
  async function  logout(){
    await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`+"/logout",{credentials:"include"}).then((res)=>{res.json().then((data)=>{setLogin(data.message)})});
  }
  function save(post){
    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}`+"/success",{title: post.title,content: post.content,image: file},{headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    withCredentials: true});
  }
  return (
    <StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={login?<User/>:<Login click={click}/>}></Route>
          <Route path="/createpost" element={login?<CreatePost post={post} change={change} click={save}/>:<Login click={click}/>}></Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}></Route>
          <Route path="/post" element={login ? <Post/> : <Login click={click}/>}></Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={login ? <Dashboard/> : <Login click={click}/>}> </Route>
          <Route path="/edit" element={login?<Edit/> : <Login click={click}/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </StrictMode>
  )
}
export default App;
```

This is my server/index.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import passport from 'passport';
import session from 'express-session';
import passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose';
import {Strategy as GoogleStrategy} from 'passport-google-oauth20';
import findOrCreate from 'mongoose-findorcreate';
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';
import { unlink } from 'node:fs';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ path: './.env'});
import MongoDBSession from 'connect-mongodb-session';
const MongoDBStore = MongoDBSession(session);
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB).then(()=>{
  console.log("Connected to database");
}).catch((err)=>{
  console.log(err.message);
})
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: process.env.COOKIE,
  collection: 'sessions',
});

store.on('error', function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(cors({
  origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
  credentials: true,
  methods:  "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE"
}));
app.set("trust proxy",1);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({
    secret: "Our little Secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: store,
  }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
   
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';
import { CloudinaryStorage } from 'multer-storage-cloudinary';
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name:process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
    api_secret:process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET
});

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary,
    params: {
        folder: 'CloudinaryDemo',
        allowedFormats: ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
    }                                                              
});
const upload = multer({ storage });
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    image: String,
    email: {type: String},
    googleId: String,
    post: [{
      title: String,
      content: String,
      image: String,
      like: {
        n: {type: Number, default: 0},
        likedBy: [String]
      },
      comments: [{
        comment: String,
        user: String,
        image: String
      }],
      date: Date,
      public_id: String
    }]
});
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);
const USER = new mongoose.model('USER',userSchema);
passport.use(USER.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });
  
  passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done) {
    try {
      const user = await USER.findById(id);
      done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      done(err, null);
    }
  });
  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL:process.env.URL + "/auth/google/test",
    userProfileURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo",
    scope: ["profile","email"]
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    USER.findOrCreate({
      email: profile.emails[0].value,
      name: profile.displayName,
      googleId: profile.id,
      image: profile.photos[0].value,
    }, function(err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.json({message:"hello"});
})
app.post('/',function(req,res){
    const newUser = new USER({ 
        ...req.body.user
    });
    console.log(newUser);
    newUser.save().then(()=>{
        console.log("Added successfully");
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err.message);
    });
})
app.get('/success',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    USER.find().then((foundUsers)=>{
      if (foundUsers){
        res.json({message: true,user: foundUsers,img: req.user.image});
      }
    });
  }else{
    res.json({message:false});
  }
});
app.post('/success',upload.single("image"),async function(req,res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
    const newpost = {
      title: req.body.title,
      content: req.body.content,
      image: req.file.path,
      date: Date.now(),
      public_id:result.public_id
    }
    
    console.log(result.public_id);
    USER.findById(req.user.id).then((foundUser)=>{
      if (foundUser){
        foundUser.post.push(newpost);
        foundUser.save();
      }
    })
  }
});
app.post("/success/like",function(req,res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    let ind = 0;
    USER.findById({_id: req.body.id}).then((foundUser)=>{
     foundUser.post.filter((p,i)=>{
      if (p._id == req.body._id){
        ind = i;
      }})
      var n = -1;
      if (foundUser.post[ind].like.likedBy.length === 0){
        n = -1;
      }
      else{
        if (foundUser){
          const index = foundUser.post[ind].like.likedBy.findIndex((u,i)=>{
            if (req.user._id == u){
              return true;
            }     
          })
          n = index;
        }
      }
      let a = 0;
      if (n!=-1){
        a = -1;
      }
      else {
        a = 1;
      }
      foundUser.post[ind].like.n = foundUser.post[ind].like.n + a;
      if (a===-1){
        const arr = foundUser.post[ind].like.likedBy.filter((u)=>{
          return u!=req.user._id;
        })
        foundUser.post[ind].like.likedBy = arr;
      }
      else {
        foundUser.post[ind].like.likedBy.push(req.user._id);
      }

      foundUser.save();
      res.json({message:true,n: n});
    }).catch((err)=>{
      res.json(err);
    })
  }
});
app.post("/edit",upload.single("image"),function(req,res){
  console.log(false);
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    const title = req.body.title;
    let image = "";
    if (req.file){
      image = req.file.path;
    }
    const content = req.body.content;
    USER.findById({_id: req.body.id}).then(async (foundUser)=>{
      let ind = 0;
      const a = foundUser.post.filter((p,i)=>{
        if (p._id==req.body.pid){
          ind = i;
        }
        return p._id==req.body.pid;
      });
      if (image==""){
        image = a[0].image;
      }else {
        await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(a[0].public_id);
      }
      foundUser.post[ind].title = title;
      foundUser.post[ind].content = content;
      foundUser.post[ind].image = image;
      foundUser.save();
    });
  }
})
app.post("/del",function(req,res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    USER.findById({_id: req.body.id}).then(async (foundUser)=>{
      const a = foundUser.post.filter((p,i)=>{
        return p._id != req.body.pid;
      })
      const b = foundUser.post.filter((p,i)=>{
        return p._id == req.body.pid;
      })
      foundUser.post = a;
      console.log(b[0].public_id);
      await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(b[0].public_id);
      foundUser.save();
    })
  }
});
app.post("/success/check",function(req,res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    let ind = 0;
    USER.findById({_id: req.body.id}).then((foundUser)=>{
      foundUser.post.filter((p,i)=>{
        if (p._id == req.body.pid){
          ind = i;
        }
      });
      let n = -1;
      foundUser.post[ind].like.likedBy.filter((l,i)=>{
        if (l==req.user._id){
          n = 1;
        }
      })
      if (n==1){
        res.json({message: true,like: foundUser.post[ind].like.n,comment: foundUser.post[ind].comments});
      }
      else{
        res.json({message: false,like: foundUser.post[ind].like.n,comment: foundUser.post[ind].comments});
      }
    }).catch((err)=>{
      res.json(err);
    })
  }
})
app.get("/dashboard",function(req,res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.json({user: req.user});
  }
})
app.post("/success/comment",function(req,res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    let ind = 0;
    USER.findById({_id: req.body.id}).then((foundUser)=>{
     foundUser.post.filter((p,i)=>{
      if (p._id == req.body._id){
        ind = i;
      }})
      console.log(req.body.comment);
    let newComment = {
      comment: req.body.comment,
      user:  req.user.name,
      image: req.user.image
    }
    foundUser.post[ind].comments.push(newComment);
    foundUser.save().then(()=>{
      res.json({user: req.user.name,image: req.user.image});
    })
  })}})
app.route("/logout")
  .get(function(req, res) {
    req.logout(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    res.json({message:"logout"});
  });
app.route('/auth/google')
  .get(passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ["profile","email"]
  }));
app.route('/auth/google/test')
  .get(passport.authenticate('google', {
    failureRedirect: '/failure',
    successRedirect: process.env.CLIENT_URL
  }));
  app.route('/failure')
  .get(function(req,res) {
    res.json({message:"failure"});
  })
app.listen(3000||process.env.Port,function(){
       console.log('Server is running on the port 3000');
});
```

I am not able to authenticate my client side. When ever my client tries to authenticate my backend got authenticate but the client unable to use cookie to authenticate itself due to which my app is not working. I don't know why this is happening.

I have set the environment variables correctly. Nothing just a loop of authenticating. The fetch and Axios is not able to use the credentials. I am unable to set the login true. Don't know why it is happening working fine on localhost but not working when deployed online.